# За "Искожем" или за "Искожом"?

Tags: склонение, окончания

Завод (предприятие) называется "Искож" (Искусственная кожа). Какое окончание верно? По правилам, 2-е склонение творительного падежа с окончанием в конце должно иметь окончание ОМ. Но... сомнения... язык не поворачивается так сказать. Может, я чего-то не знаю. Интуитивно хочется сказать -ЕМ.

Comment: А чё, если света, то и искож. интуитивно со строчной.

Answer (score 1):

```
    2 склонение творительного падежа с окончанием в конце
```

Ударение может быть подвижным - переходить с основы на окончание, а может и не переходить, оставаться на основе. Искож - составное название. Нормой было бы его вообще не склонять: я живу за заводом "Искож", кто стоит за ОАО "Искож"?

В разговорном стиле склонение возможно, но, вероятно, окончание будет безударным:
От "Искожа", за "Искожем", об "Искоже".